# Shared Context for ASP and WPF Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I have an issue with a shared context that I used for ASP(MCV) and WPF(MVVM) App.

Both app are using
1. Shared Context
2. Shared Data Model
3. Shared Local MSSQL database

The problem: If i run the WPF application in other Computer, I've always got following Error: underlying provider failed on open.

In the Context Class, which is used for both ASP and WPF app the standard ASP built in was implemented:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
    }
}
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {

        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        return userIdentity;
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the App Setting xml:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Civetta\App_Data\aspnet-Civetta-20170824060118.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Civetta-20170824060118;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Could you give a hint or two how to solve this problem please?

Thank you so much for your help
SD

Comment: You shouldn't have shared context. Just use it's own sontext for each application. Even better - 2 separate users to connect to db.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, So thats mean that I'll have DBsets for each context?. I have create my DB with codefirst method.

Comment: I mead you should have 2 separate instanses od context in your applications

Comment: Thanks the input, but i still not quite satisfied, since I need to choose a namespace everytime I compile the whole solution. Would you show me your idea in detail please. Tx